# How to resize a picturebox in the user control when a button is clicked in the form?

Tags: c#, winforms

So I am new to c#, and this User Controls are making a mess in my head.

Currently am working on to create a user Control, which should act as a progress bar, so I thought initially I can try and use a panel and put a picture box in it, thus showing its progress, and in my Form i have a 2 buttons stating next and back. Its like a progress bar mostly used in wizards for detecting the steps. Consider I have 15 steps and when i press the Next button the picture box should expand with the ratio of (width_of_the_panel/15(no of steps)). I am confused about were can i write the resize_method. If I mention it in userControl how can I access it from my Form?

```
private void image_size()
{
    if (pictureBox1.Image.Width < pictureBox1.Width && pictureBox1.Image.Height < pictureBox1.Height)
    {
        pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Normal;
    }
    else
    {
        pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
    }
    int wid = panel1.Width / val;
    Image img = new Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
    Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(img);
    gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
    gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    gr.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
    gr.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, wid, panel1.Height);
}
```

Comment: WPF? Winforms? ASP.NET?

Comment: Do you have any code showing what you've tried already?

Comment: On the user control, make a increase progress method that increases the picturebox size (width?)

Comment: yes, what framework are you using WinForms or WPF?? you got some code?

Comment: I am Using winforms.... the code is a simple one. i have edited my question, you may have a look over it... please help me how can i call this function when the button is clicked

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular progress bar, the one provided with .NET. Use [ProgressBar.Maximum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.maximum.aspx) and [ProgressBar.Step](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.step.aspx) properties, to suit your wizard style. If you need customization, you can inherit from `ProgressBar`, or create a composite `UserControl` with a `ProgressBar` on it. There is no need to reinvent the wheel and create your own `ProgressBar` from scratch.